# How to prove the equality $ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(m-1)^k}{m^{k+1}}(k+1) = m$ for any natural $m > 1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to prove the equality
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(m-1)^k}{m^{k+1}}(k+1) = m
$$
for any natural $m > 1$? I checked it for the first naturals $m$ by means of https://www.wolframalpha.com. However, I need a proof in general.

Comment: Set $x=(m-1)/m$ and then see, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1987957/42969

Answer (score 0):

Writing the series like this
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{m}\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^k,
$$
the $(k+1)x^k$ form strongly suggests this comes from the derivative of something of the form $x^{k+1}$. The obvious first try is $x = ((m-1)/m)$, which gives $(k+1)((m-1)/m)^k /m^2$. So we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{m}\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^k = m\frac{d}{dm}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^{k+1} = m\frac{d}{dm}\left(m-1\right) = m
$$